# How to change backslash to forwardslash using the public_path method

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using the **[IMAGINE](https://github.com/orchestral/imagine)** package in laravel , I have the below line in laravel:

```
 $path = public_path('img\testsave\/' .$filename);
```

now I'm getting the following error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\lookinggood\public/img\testsave/2015-10-07-11-40-19-edit-one.jpgjpg
>   does not exist.

The backslash after `public` needs to be changed to a forward
slash. After `testsave` I am getting the `\/` .

I have tried to escape the forward slash like so:

```
$path = public_path('img\testsave\/' .$filename);
```

So how do I change the backslash after public to a forwardslash and how do I successfully escape the forward slash after `testsave` ?

Comment: @RyanVincent get `C:\xampp\htdocs\lookinggood\public/img/testsave/2015-10-07-12-03-09-edit-one.jpg does not exist.` and i have the following line now , `             $path = public_path("img/testsave/" .$filename);
`

Comment: @RyanVincent , i am getting http://i.imgur.com/NrwiIIX.jpg this error

Comment: @RyanVincent `Ok - what is in the testsave directory that looks like a .jpg file?` what do u mean by that ?

Comment: This is a tested script [File Paths on windows: - Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/QUVU2GqZ) that demonstrates about windows not caring about '\' or '/' as directory name separators. Tested on windows XP - PHP 5.3.29.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use implode and explode functions in php

to read more about these functions follow the links

implode : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

explode : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp